# Run package sql file in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I used a script sql file to create package in Liquibase. But after updating liquibase only package created, not for package body.

Please see my below code

```
create or replace package BUILD2TEST.MyPackage is    
  /* my code */
END MyPackage;    
create or replace package body BUILD2TEST.MyPackage is    
    /* my code */
end MyPackage;
```

Do you know why liquibase can't create the package body ?

My changeset

```
 <changeSet author="taibc" id="sqlFile-example2">
<sqlFile dbms="h2, oracle"
        encoding="utf8"
        endDelimiter="\nGO"
        path="CreatePackage.sql"
        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        splitStatements="true"
        stripComments="true"/>
  <rollback>
    DROP PACKAGE BUILD2TEST.MyPackage;         
</rollback>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong delimiter in your sql file.

try with this:

```
create or replace package BUILD2TEST.MyPackage is    
  /* my code */
END MyPackage; 
/
create or replace package body BUILD2TEST.MyPackage is    
    /* my code */
end MyPackage;
/
```

and change your delimiter to this:

```
<changeSet author="taibc" id="sqlFile-example2">
<sqlFile dbms="h2, oracle"
        encoding="utf8"
        endDelimiter="\n/"
        path="CreatePackage.sql"
        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        splitStatements="true"
        stripComments="true"/>
  <rollback>
    DROP PACKAGE BUILD2TEST.MyPackage;         
</rollback>
```

at least this should work for oracle

Comment: Great. Thank you